# Symfony, FOSUserBundle keep user logged in

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am currently using Symfony 2.8 together with FOSUserBundle 2.0 and I want to make sure that the logged in user is remembered. Means I can always check if the user is currently logged in.

Is there a way? In other projects I used FOS 1.3 and Symfony 2.3 and there was a function called authenticateUser to keep the user logged in.

Im thankful for any help or tips.

EDIT: I think I am just missing something essential.

I am checking the credentials with:

```
if($encoder->isPasswordValid($teacher->getPassword(), $password, null))
```

but im not actively setting the user to the state logged on. How exactly do I have to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with this if a user is logged in or not

```
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
//do something
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I forgot that im not using the twigs. I am using angularjs for the frontend. Means I have a basic twig where my components are loaded in and the rest is handled via angularjs. 

I also think that I am doing a basic mistake in logging in.  

I am checking the credentials with            if($encoder->isPasswordValid($teacher->getPassword(), $password, null)) but how exactly do I login.